# Is there a more effective way to combine 24 columns into a single column as an array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a code below that works to take 24 columns (hours) of data and combine it into a single column array for each row in a dataframe:

```
# Adds all of the values into column twentyfourhours with "," as the separator.
agg_bluetooth_data$twentyfourhours <- paste(agg_bluetooth_data[,1],
agg_bluetooth_data[,2], agg_bluetooth_data[,3], agg_bluetooth_data[,4],
agg_bluetooth_data[,5], agg_bluetooth_data[,6], agg_bluetooth_data[,7],
agg_bluetooth_data[,8], agg_bluetooth_data[,9], agg_bluetooth_data[,10],
agg_bluetooth_data[,11], agg_bluetooth_data[,12], agg_bluetooth_data[,13],
agg_bluetooth_data[,14], agg_bluetooth_data[,15], agg_bluetooth_data[,16],
agg_bluetooth_data[,17], agg_bluetooth_data[,18], agg_bluetooth_data[,19],
agg_bluetooth_data[,20], agg_bluetooth_data[,21], agg_bluetooth_data[,22],
agg_bluetooth_data[,23], agg_bluetooth_data[,24], sep=",")
```

However, after this I still have to write more lines of code to remove spaces, add brackets around it, and delete the columns.  None of this is difficult to do, but I feel like there should be a shorter/cleaner code to use to get the results I am looking for.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function to do `rowSums`.  It looks like you want an analogous `rowPaste` function.  We can do this with `apply`:

```
# create example dataset
df <- data.frame(
    v=1:10,
    x=letters[1:10],
    y=letters[6:15],
    z=letters[11:20],
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# rowPaste columns 2 through 4
apply(df[, 2:4], 1, paste, collapse=",")
```

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for:
`agg_bluetooth_data$twentyfourhours <- apply(agg_bluetooth_data[, 1:24], 1, paste, collapse=",")`

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using @Dan Y's data (might be helpful if you posted a subset of your data using `dput` though).

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  unite('new_col', v, x, y, z, sep = ',') 

    new_col
1   1,a,f,k
2   2,b,g,l
3   3,c,h,m
4   4,d,i,n
5   5,e,j,o
6   6,f,k,p
7   7,g,l,q
8   8,h,m,r
9   9,i,n,s
10 10,j,o,t
```

You can then perform the neccessary edits with `mutate`. There's also a fair amount of flexibility in the column selections within the `unite` call. Check out the "Useful Functions" section of [the select documentation.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.6/topics/select)